# Waiting till component variable is set by subscribe

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, http, async-await

I have to calls in my component. The secound depends on the result from the first call.At the first call, I set the value for my component variable "locked". The secound call should be executed when the result is true --> locked = true. But it will reach the code, before the first call is finished and the value is set. How can I wait with the execution of my code, until the call "getByUsernamer" is finished.

Here is my code:

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  
  errorMessage: string = "";
  isLocked = false;
  username: string | null = "";

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private cookieService: CookieService,
    private router: Router,
    private jwtTokenService: JwtTokenService,
    private userService: UserService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  test() {
    this.userService.getUserByUsername(this.username)?.subscribe(
      {
        next: response => {
          let user: User = response;
          this.isLocked = user.locked
        }
      }
    );

    if (!this.isLocked) {
      this.router.navigate(['/home']).finally(
        () => this.userService.setLastLogin(this.username).subscribe());
    } else {
      this.errorMessage = "The user is locked."
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `isLocked` variable in the callback of the first call, so you are sure that you received the answer and the `isLocked` variable is set

```
export class LoginComponent implements OnInit {
  
  errorMessage: string = "";
  isLocked = false;
  username: string | null = "";

  constructor(
    private authService: AuthService,
    private cookieService: CookieService,
    private router: Router,
    private jwtTokenService: JwtTokenService,
    private userService: UserService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  test() {
    this.userService.getUserByUsername(this.username)?.subscribe(
      {
        next: response => {
          let user: User = response;
          this.isLocked = user.locked;

          // Moved here the test so it happens only after 
          // the first request  receive the answer
          if (!this.isLocked) {
            this.router.navigate(['/home']).finally(() => this.userService.setLastLogin(this.username).subscribe());
          } else {
            this.errorMessage = "The user is locked."
          }
        }
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: okay thanks.. but I thought it isn´t good to make a subscribe in a subscribe.